# subversion svn: subdirectory deleted from working copy but update doesn't bring it back

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I just had a problem with a tree conflict in subversion/tortoisesvn. after a lot of faffing about, reverting and clean ups, it got into the state where one existing subtree was shown as "added" (there was no _svn directory inside it), even though the subtree was identical to the repository. so I deleted that subtree thinking an update would bring it back again

however, to my surprise, update doesn't bring this directory back and the commit and check for changes windows both imply that I am completely up to date.

of course i can just checkout a new working copy so i'm not that worried about rescuing it, but my concern is more that I currently have a working copy that I know has a big chunk missing but the tool seems to think is fine. this doesn't seem very good for a version control system, and I'm worried about the consequences if this happened again in future without my noticing it.

is there any tool i can use to force a complete re-scan of my working copy, or to spot these kind of inconsistencies?

thanks

Andy

Comment: Have you marked the conflict as solved? I assume that the directory is excluded from update because of a conflict.

Comment: no, that's the odd thing, there was no indication of any change of conflict being made; subversion was reporting the copy as 100% clean. I've sorted it out now using stefan's method below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the "update to revision" command, then set the update depth to "fully recursive" in the dialog.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, that seems to have sorted it out (eventually).

I tried to do an update to the latest revision with fully recursive but it didn't do anything, so I updated to a previous revision which contained a change to the affected subdirectory which gave an error about the working directory being missing. Then I did another update which seems to have restored it all.

It's not really a solution to the problem of how to spot if a working copy has got into this situation, but it did rescue my woking copy without having to do a complete checkout.